# Question:if $z=-1-i$ then what is $z^8$

Tags: complex-numbers

For the question if $z=-1-i$ then what is $z^8$? The correct answer  is $32e^{10πi}$ which doesn't make sense since I am getting $16e^{10πi}$.

Comment: your answer is correct

Comment: You are right. The problem with this "solution" is that $2^{8/2}=2^{4}=16$ and not 32.

Comment: The answer in the book is clearly wrong: $|z| = \sqrt{2}$, so $|z^8| = 16$.

Comment: thanks i was at this question for hours  should have doubted my answer

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is "none of the above."

$(-1-i)^2=2i$, so $(-1-i)^8=(2i)^4=2^4i^4=16.$

(This agrees with the answer you wrote, because $e^{10\pi i}=(e^{2\pi i})^5=1.$)